# Grails query not inList

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I'm writing a criteria to make a query, but I can't figure out how to negate an inList criteria...Is there a way to do something like:

```
def result = c {
     not inList('id', ids)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your criteria should like this...

```
def ids = [1, 2, 3];

def c = Foo.createCriteria();
def results = c.list {
  not {'in'("id",ids)}
}
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).  I believe this was just added in grails 2.+

Comment: you're right...except for the fact that the not method doesn't seem exists

Comment: @rascio Probably pointless to add, since more than 3 years have passed, but.. need to cast to array before passing (toArray()).